# Is it possible to transfer files between Android devices via scp?

Tags: android, scp, file-transfer, termux

I'm trying to transfer files between Android devices via the scp protocol. Is this possible? I keep getting:

`ssh: unable to connect to host [remote ip address] port 22: Connection refused scp connection closed`

after using the command

`scp testFile.txt remoteDevice@ipAddress:path/to/directory`

I can ssh into each device without issue, but the scp function seems to not work. Am I asking too much from my Android devices, do I need to download an additional module via termux, or is this simply not possible?

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's totally possible. Maybe it's just missing the port at your command (which should be 8022).

**A quick step-by-step of what you need to make it work:**

First you need to configure the remote ssh server at the target termux. Check the termux [documentation here](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access).

Then, you have to start the remote ssh server:

```
sshd
```

Finally, copy your files. Remember: the termux sshd port is 8022, then your command will be like this:

```
scp -P 8022 ./file.txt user@192.168.15.104:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/folder/file.txt
```

- Obviously, change the IP according to your server IP
- I'd recommend informing the full path (like in my example above), instead of ~/folder/file.txt

If your remote ssh is correctly configured and running, it should work.